# How to solve the differential equation $x'=\cos(x)-(x+1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \cos(x)-(x+1)$$

I think I need to separate the variable and use euler formula to describe the $\cos(x)$? Like $\cos(x)= \dfrac{\exp(ix) + \exp (-ix)}2\;?$

Answer (score 2):

The variables are already separated since
$$
\frac{x'(t)}{a(x(t))}=1,\qquad a(z)=\cos(z)-z-1
$$
hence
$$
\int_{x(0)}^{x(t)}\frac{\mathrm du}{a(u)}=t,
$$
a formula which cannot be inverted with only usual functions.

Note that the function $a$ is decreasing with $a(0)=0$ and that $a(z)\sim-z$ when $|z|\to\infty$ and when $z\to0$. Hence, for every $x(t_0)\ne0$, the function $t\mapsto x(t)$ is defined on the whole line and is increasing from $x(-\infty)=-\infty$ to $x(+\infty)=0$ if $x(t_0)\lt0$, while it is decreasing from $x(-\infty)=+\infty$ to $x(+\infty)=0$ if $x(t_0)\gt0$. If $x(t_0)=0$, then $x(t)=0$ for every $t$.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for all advises! Do I get some logarythm on the end?  After I integrate?

Comment: Please read: `...a formula which cannot be inverted with only usual functions.` Logarithms are "usual functions".

Answer (score 0):

From the equation,

$\displaystyle \frac{dx}{\cos(x) - (x+1)} = dt$.

Now we have separated the $x$ terms on the left side from the $t$ term on the right side. From this,

$\displaystyle \int \frac{dx}{\cos(x) - (x+1)} = t + C$,

where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

Now the problem is to solve the integral above.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I try to solve this but doesn´t work well :(